# Replace new lines at end for those lines whose 2nd field in colon separated file span over to multiple line

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, perl

I have got multiple files with different set of contents but the pattern is same across mulitple lines in different files.

sample input file  :  cat -n test.txt

```
     1  adjfkhjdhfkjd: dfkjfkdljgklfjgklfjgkfjghk
     2  rtueitjrkldngfmdn: kldfjkdjgkdjgkldjgkfjhklfjkkjhkgjhklfk
     3  dkljfkdljgkldg: fgdkjgkfdljglkfdjgkldfjgkljkldfjgkljgkflj
     4  a12kjsdk232kjk445kjkjlk34323lkjkjlk3422
     5  98094kjhjkh23434hjhk32453242hkjhkjhkj
     6  bncvmcnbxmbvcnmxbvnxbcnxbnxcmbvnxc: xckdfjgklfdjgklfdjglkfdjgio
     7  iourtiourtioreutiorutoir: i3948j35hj4309457480jkh5jk450
     8  5ui43u3213435
     9  5io4p3i54op3i5op34i5po34i5
    10  54390859043860943853kj5h34jkh534jk543
    11  jkljkljkjkjkjklj: hgjjjjjjjjjjjjj
    12  4i34935kjtkrelthrket: 4539859435943hkjhkjhk34543ll4
    13  jg;lfdjglkfjlkfjghlkfd
    14  f;dgljdfl;hj;df
    15  fglkdjlkjgkldfjgklfdjhklfhjdflkj
```

Expected output :

```
adjfkhjdhfkjd: dfkjfkdljgklfjgklfjgkfjghk
rtueitjrkldngfmdn: kldfjkdjgkdjgkldjgkfjhklfjkkjhkgjhklfk
dkljfkdljgkldg: fgdkjgkfdljglkfdjgkldfjgkljkldfjgkljgkflj a12kjsdk232kjk445kjkjlk34323lkjkjlk3422 98094kjhjkh23434hjhk32453242hkjhkjhkj
bncvmcnbxmbvcnmxbvnxbcnxbnxcmbvnxc: xckdfjgklfdjgklfdjglkfdjgio
iourtiourtioreutiorutoir: i3948j35hj4309457480jkh5jk450 5ui43u3213435 5io4p3i54op3i5op34i5po34i5 54390859043860943853kj5h34jkh534jk543
jkljkljkjkjkjklj: hgjjjjjjjjjjjjj
4i34935kjtkrelthrket: 4539859435943hkjhkjhk34543ll4 lfdjglkfjlkfjghlkfd f;dgljdfl;hj;df fglkdjlkjgkldfjgklfdjhklfhjdflkj
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done to solve your problem?

Comment: (a) Noted that the output text is not contiguous -- newlines before trailing lines are replaced by spaces ?
(b) Can you specify a maximum on the length of any output line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this variant of a well-known sed recipe:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;/\n.*:/!s/\n/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' test.txt
```

i.e. append a line to the previous (by replacing newline with space) if it does **not** contain a colon. So given

```
$ cat -n test.txt
     1  adjfkhjdhfkjd: dfkjfkdljgklfjgklfjgkfjghk
     2  rtueitjrkldngfmdn: kldfjkdjgkdjgkldjgkfjhklfjkkjhkgjhklfk
     3  dkljfkdljgkldg: fgdkjgkfdljglkfdjgkldfjgkljkldfjgkljgkflj
     4  a12kjsdk232kjk445kjkjlk34323lkjkjlk3422
     5  98094kjhjkh23434hjhk32453242hkjhkjhkj
     6  bncvmcnbxmbvcnmxbvnxbcnxbnxcmbvnxc: xckdfjgklfdjgklfdjglkfdjgio
     7  iourtiourtioreutiorutoir: i3948j35hj4309457480jkh5jk450
     8  5ui43u3213435
     9  5io4p3i54op3i5op34i5po34i5
    10  54390859043860943853kj5h34jkh534jk543
    11  jkljkljkjkjkjklj: hgjjjjjjjjjjjjj
    12  4i34935kjtkrelthrket: 4539859435943hkjhkjhk34543ll4
    13  jg;lfdjglkfjlkfjghlkfd
    14  f;dgljdfl;hj;df
    15  fglkdjlkjgkldfjgklfdjhklfhjdflkj
```

then

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;/\n.*:/!s/\n/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' test.txt | cat -n
     1  adjfkhjdhfkjd: dfkjfkdljgklfjgklfjgkfjghk
     2  rtueitjrkldngfmdn: kldfjkdjgkdjgkldjgkfjhklfjkkjhkgjhklfk
     3  dkljfkdljgkldg: fgdkjgkfdljglkfdjgkldfjgkljkldfjgkljgkflj a12kjsdk232kjk445kjkjlk34323lkjkjlk3422 98094kjhjkh23434hjhk32453242hkjhkjhkj
     4  bncvmcnbxmbvcnmxbvnxbcnxbnxcmbvnxc: xckdfjgklfdjgklfdjglkfdjgio
     5  iourtiourtioreutiorutoir: i3948j35hj4309457480jkh5jk450 5ui43u3213435 5io4p3i54op3i5op34i5po34i5 54390859043860943853kj5h34jkh534jk543
     6  jkljkljkjkjkjklj: hgjjjjjjjjjjjjj
     7  4i34935kjtkrelthrket: 4539859435943hkjhkjhk34543ll4 jg;lfdjglkfjlkfjghlkfd f;dgljdfl;hj;df fglkdjlkjgkldfjgklfdjhklfhjdflkj
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk '{printf "%s", (($1 ~ /:$/) ? ((NR==1) ? "" : ORS) : " ")$0 } END{print ""}' file
# Or
$ awk -v ORS=' ' '{NR!=1 && gsub(/[[:alnum:]]+:/, "\n&")}1; END{printf "\n"}' file | sed 's/ $//'
```

As suggested by @EdMorton:

> Always do `printf "%s", $n` instead of `printf $n` as the latter will fail when the input contains printf formatting chars like `%s`, and `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` as the former uses whatever value ORS has while the latter uses the hard-coded value that you hope ORS has.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/:/{if (NR>1) print r; r=$0; next} {r=r OFS $0} END{print r}' file
adjfkhjdhfkjd: dfkjfkdljgklfjgklfjgkfjghk
rtueitjrkldngfmdn: kldfjkdjgkdjgkldjgkfjhklfjkkjhkgjhklfk
dkljfkdljgkldg: fgdkjgkfdljglkfdjgkldfjgkljkldfjgkljgkflj a12kjsdk232kjk445kjkjlk34323lkjkjlk3422 98094kjhjkh23434hjhk32453242hkjhkjhkj
bncvmcnbxmbvcnmxbvnxbcnxbnxcmbvnxc: xckdfjgklfdjgklfdjglkfdjgio
iourtiourtioreutiorutoir: i3948j35hj4309457480jkh5jk450 5ui43u3213435 5io4p3i54op3i5op34i5po34i5 54390859043860943853kj5h34jkh534jk543
jkljkljkjkjkjklj: hgjjjjjjjjjjjjj
4i34935kjtkrelthrket: 4539859435943hkjhkjhk34543ll4 jg;lfdjglkfjlkfjghlkfd f;dgljdfl;hj;df fglkdjlkjgkldfjgklfdjhklfhjdflkj
```